# In JavaScript, after I set an attribute of an object array, why does the item remain undefined?

Tags: javascript

Firstly, I inherited a large project and have the task of maintaining/enhancing it.  In the code elsewhere, the previous developer uses/used an object for the Timezone, which has three attributes.

Recently, I had to add the Reading Timezone to a form.  On the web page form, in a Angular datasheet, in a field that is a select box for choosing a SystemTimeZone, the user can choose the timezone without problems.  I am using the TimezoneOffset as the ID in the list for the select box, with the Timezone Name showing in the box.  Currently, we only have one timezone, so the offset shows GMT, Standard, and Daylight Savings times work very well.

Later on in my code, I want to change the type of the timezone from the number that came from the select box, to the full SystemTimeZone object that shows the Description, Name, and TimezoneOffset, in order to reuse the previous developer's code.

Here is the code for the SystemTimezones from my config.js file.  The variable is part of $scope.

```
var SystemTimezones = [
{
    "Name" : "Pacific Standard Time (GMT-08:00)",
    "Description" : "(GMT-08:00) Pacific Standard Time (US & Canada)",
    "TimezoneOffset" : -8 * millis_per_h,
}, 
{
    "Name" : "Pacific Daylight Time (GMT-07:00)",
    "Description" : "(GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (US & Canada)",
    "TimezoneOffset" : -7 * millis_per_h,
},
{
    "Name" : "Greenwich Mean Time (GMT-00:00)",
    "Description" : "(GMT-00:00) Greenwich Mean Time",
    "TimezoneOffset" : 0,
}
];
```

Here is the code, where I am trying to set (or reset) what the item is.

```
$scope.saveData = function() {
    console.log("Inside saveData...");
    console.log("$scope is Next...");
    console.dir($scope);

    var intdataSheetDatasetLength = $scope.dataSheetDataset.length;
    var intSystemTimezonesLength = $scope.SystemTimezones.length;
    console.log("intdataSheetDatasetLength = " + intdataSheetDatasetLength + ", intSystemTimezonesLength = " + intSystemTimezonesLength);
    for (var dd = 0; dd < intdataSheetDatasetLength; dd++)
    {               
        for (var st = 0; st < intSystemTimezonesLength; st++)
        {
            console.log("dd = " + dd + ", st = " + st);
            console.log("$scope.SystemTimezones[st].TimezoneOffset = " + $scope.SystemTimezones[st].TimezoneOffset + ", $scope.dataSheetDataset[dd].Timezone = " + $scope.dataSheetDataset[dd].Timezone);       
            if ($scope.SystemTimezones[st].TimezoneOffset.toString() === $scope.dataSheetDataset[dd].Timezone.toString())
            {
                var tmpTimezone = $scope.dataSheetDataset[dd].Timezone;
                console.log("tmpTimezone = " + tmpTimezone);
                //$scope.dataSheetDataset[dd].Timezone = undefined;
                console.log("$scope.SystemTimezones[st] = ");
                console.dir($scope.SystemTimezones[st]);
                $scope.dataSheetDataset[dd].Timezone = $scope.SystemTimezones[st];
                console.log("$scope.dataSheetDataset[dd].Timezone = ");
                console.dir($scope.dataSheetDataset[dd].Timezone);
                st = intSystemTimezonesLength;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("$scope.dataSheetDataset is next...");
    console.dir($scope.dataSheetDataset);
};
```

When the code runs, after I set the item, in the IE debug window, I can see that the update took place.  However, after leaving the loop and outputting the contents of $scope.dataSheetDataset again, the Timezone is undefined.

Can anyone tell me, why this is happening?

Comment: The submission has a type-o inside the if, where the console statement is missing the semicolon; this issue is not in the project code.

Comment: Looks like unmatched braces on the if() statement.

Comment: RE:  var SystemTimezones should be $scope.SystemTimezones:  Although these snippets do not show it here, SystemTimezones is part of the $scope, set elsewhere.  When I output the variable via console.dir($scope), SystemTimezones is part of it.

Comment: Can you repost the code without the syntax errors?

Comment: RE:  Looks like unmatched braces on the if() statement:  Actually, the lines from the console.log("$scope.SystemTimezones[st] = "); and below should be shifted to the right 4 spaces.  I got side-tracked and forgot to finish doing that before submitting.  Also, the opening { after $scope.saveData at the top has a closing } , not shown, farther down below.

Comment: Just post the corrected code, don't waste time telling us all the details.

Comment: RE:  Repost without the syntax errors:  I will do that.

Comment: Updated the code, removing syntax errors.

Comment: Can you make a [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?